# Github API field descriptions

Tags: github, github-api

I'm toying with the [Github search API (v3)](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/) and can't seem to find a description of the fields that are returned.  Most of them are obvious, but there are a few like `score` that aren't.  Does anyone know what `score` means, and does a field reference exist?

Answer (score 3):

The `score` attribute is the search score of that document for a particular query, and is used for [Best Match sorting](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-github#sorting-results). In other words, it's used for ranking search results, but it isn't shown in [search results on github.com](https://github.com/search?q=search+is+the+best&type=Code).

Comment: It sounds plausible, but do you know if this is documented?  I don't see a reference to that field in your first link.

Comment: It's not documented, other than in the Search API documentation where you just see the attribute listed in the example response. You'll notice that (in general) the API docs do not explain what each attribute in responses means. Instead, you just get the example response and it should be clear what each attribute means. When you search on github.com - you don't get this score; you just get search results sorted using this score. But the API gives you this in the response because they might be useful. (Note: I work at GitHub. You can always contact support@github.com if you have more questions)

Comment: Thanks Ivan!  As you said, most of them are obvious.  The score - not so much.  I guess this will have to do =).

Comment: @IvanZuzak Now the `score` attribute is documented [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#ranking-search-results), by our friend Wynn! See [this pull request](https://github.com/github/developer.github.com/pull/456). :)